# Git log for a set of commits

Tags: bash, git

I am trying to get `git log --name-only` for a set of commits I have.
I can use a bash script to loop through the commits, but I wanted to know if there is a better way.

For example: 
If have thousands of commits in a database, how can I get the git log information for just 3 commits which are randomly picked?

Any insights appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: 3 *consecutive* commits?

Comment: No they are not consecutive. And it may not be just 3.

Comment: random commits, would you have any filter criteria, or they are completely random?

Comment: They are completely random. @ArkadiuszDrabczyk solution solved my question.

Comment: @RahulR. I believe Shrav means arbitrary commits: there are specific three commits which might not be next to each other, and Shrav wants to display information for them. Not actually three commits chosen at random from the set of all commits in the repository.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, IIUC you want `git show --name-only`:

```
git show --name-only <COMMIT_SHA1> <ANOTHER_COMMIT_SHA1>
```

For example, in `git://w1.fi/hostap.git` repository:

```
$  git show --name-only 1778f1e9a4c37aa2bad51f4027139625cf39783a 0fa669bcaeb8861cbf24544f18d22a8f39821f1a
commit 1778f1e9a4c37aa2bad51f4027139625cf39783a
Author: Jouni Malinen <jouni@codeaurora.org>
Date:   Fri Mar 23 17:57:14 2018 +0200

    SAE: Fix PTK derivation to use KDF-SHA256

    The previous implementation ended up defaulting to using PRF-SHA1 for
    deriving PTK from PMK when SAE was used. This is not correct since the
    SAE AKM is defined to be using SHA-256 -based KDF instead. Fix that.

    Note: This change is not backwards compatible. Both the AP and station
    side implementations will need to be updated at the same time to
    maintain functionality.

    Signed-off-by: Jouni Malinen <jouni@codeaurora.org>

src/common/defs.h
src/common/wpa_common.c

commit 0fa669bcaeb8861cbf24544f18d22a8f39821f1a
Author: Jouni Malinen <jouni@codeaurora.org>
Date:   Wed Mar 21 22:34:09 2018 +0200

    Fix a resource leak on hostapd maclist parsing error path

    The open file needs to be closed in error case. The conversion to using
    a new helper function (hostapd_add_acl_maclist) somehow managed to
    remove the neede fclose(f) call. Bring it back to fix this.

    Fixes: 3988046de538 ("hostapd: Dynamic MAC ACL management over control interface")
    Signed-off-by: Jouni Malinen <jouni@codeaurora.org>

hostapd/config_file.c
```

Comment: That's Neat!! Thanks